# Change SQL conversion of a SPARQL query in Virtuoso

Tags: query-optimization, sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso

From what I understand, Virtuoso converts the SPARQL queries I run on its interface (whether it is from the webapp, the console `isql` command, or from the HTTP API) to SQL, and then Virtuoso queries its internal SQL databases.

Right now, I'm trying to run a simple but time-consuming query on quite big graphs (between 1M and 10M triples, roughly): counting the number of IRIs and blank nodes in my graphs. In the case of blank nodes, I run the two following queries:

```sql
DEFINE sql:log-enable 2 
WITH <http://localhost/tcl/> 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o FILTER isBlank(?o)}
```

```sql
DEFINE sql:log-enable 2 
WITH <http://localhost/tcl/> 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o FILTER isBlank(?s)}
```

While the first one is decently fast (5-6 seconds, result is 352,550 blank nodes), the second one is comparatively very slow (~1 minute, result is 885,255 blank nodes). This behavior also happens with other graphs.
To go further in this, I tried to analyze the SQL compilation. And indeed, they are quite different.

The first query (count blank objects) decomposes as such:

```sql
SELECT  COUNT ( DISTINCT
      box_hash (
       __id2in ( "s_1_1_t0"."S"),
       __id2in ( "s_1_1_t0"."P"),
       __ro2sq ( "s_1_1_t0"."O"))) AS "callret-0"
FROM DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD AS "s_1_1_t0"
WHERE
  "s_1_1_t0"."G" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://localhost/tcl/' , 1))
  AND
  is_bnode_iri_id ( "s_1_1_t0"."O")
OPTION (QUIETCAST)
```

While the second (count blank subjects) is converted to:

```sql
SELECT  COUNT ( DISTINCT
      box_hash (
       __id2in ( "s_2_1_t0"."S"),
       __id2in ( "s_2_1_t0"."P"),
       __ro2sq ( "s_2_1_t0"."O"))) AS "callret-0"
FROM DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD AS "s_2_1_t0"
WHERE
  "s_2_1_t0"."G" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://localhost/tcl/' , 1))
  AND
  ( "s_2_1_t0"."S" >= min_bnode_iri_id ())
OPTION (QUIETCAST)
```

As you can see, the next-to-last line is different. So, curious about this difference, I tried to make up a query using the "fast" structure, but to fast "slow" results: I replaced `( "s_2_1_t0"."S" >= min_bnode_iri_id ())` by `is_bnode_iri_id ( "s_1_1_t0"."S")`.

And it worked! I got the same exact number, except way faster (9-10 seconds).

So now I want to ask: how can I change to way the SPARQL query is converted to SQL? Or is there a way to query directly the SQL databases from an external app?

These SPARQL queries are usually run in Python code, so I cannot do this manually every time.

Comment: are you sure your queries are doing what you want? `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o FILTER isBlank(?o)}` returns the number of triples with blank nodes but not as you said *"352,550 blank nodes"*

Comment: I don't know how you want to change this or whether it's possible to disable or influence the used query plan. A query optimizer is used, and is looks like a different query plan + index is used.

Comment: what I know is that you could indeed connect to the SQL database, e.g. via Python: http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/execpythonscript/

Comment: My phrasing may have been a little ambiguous. The sum of the result values of both queries gives me the number of triples with blank nodes in subject position + the number of triples with blank nodes in object position. This is equal to the number of blank nodes total in the graph if I'm not mistaken (in my situation I know in advance that there are no blank node in predicate position).

Comment: Ok, yeah as you can see in my second comment, via ODBC you can connect to the SQL database. Maybe this is all you need

Comment: I'm not using ODBC or anything like that (I'm connecting using the SPARQLWrapper library) but I'll take a look into it. Thanks for the link

Comment: Regarding *"This is equal to the number of blank nodes total in the graph if I'm not mistaken"* - I don't think this is correct. The same blank node could be reused by multiple triples in object and subject position. The graph could have `:s1 :p _:b123 .` and `:s2 :p _:b123 .` and `_:b123 :p :o1.`  which would be just 1 blank node why your computation would return 3

Comment: That is technically true, but these computations are mostly to count the prevalence of blank nodes in the graph, so my computation (which is more "*the number of positions occupied by blank nodes*" rather than "*the number of blank nodes*" indeed) feels more relevant in my situation. But your remark is correct and this is a mistake

Comment: One key question here is exactly what version (Open Source vs Enterprise and build version/date details) of Virtuoso you're running. You *may* have found a glitch in Virtuoso's query optimization routines, which would be *much* better raised to Virtuoso developers via either [OpenLink's Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com) or the [Open Source Virtuoso project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/).

Comment: I'm running the Open Source edition, with this version:

    Version: 07.20.3230
    Build: Mar 27 2019

Comment: Thank you for the version detail. It would be most helpful if you would raise this directly to the [Open Source Virtuoso project on github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), especially if you can provide test queries which might be run on arbitrary instances (e.g., DBpedia, URIBurner, a fresh install...)